# Display all duplicate records based multiple columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates, records

I'm very new to mySQL and I have tried searching all over the web and in stackoverflow as well to find a solution to probably what is a very simple query.

I have a table called Customer data, which has columns such as ID, first name, surname, Address and date of birth. I want to run a query in mySQL which will identify and display in groups all columns where first name, last name, address and DOB is identical for 2 or more records. The key thing to note here that ID is never duplicated and therefore I need to get out the IDs for each duplicated record.

I have seen many sample queries where `COUNT(*)` is used but this just displays 1 single record and the occurrence of the same record in the count column rather than bringing out the 2nd duplicated record.

A sample query I have run is this:

```
SELECT Uniq_Cust, Address, FirstName, LastName, DOB, COUNT(*) AS count1
FROM customerdata
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, DOB, Address
HAVING count1 > 1
ORDER BY count1 ASC
```

I hope I have explained what I am trying to achieve clearly. 
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This will show all pairs of records which share a first and last name:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c1 JOIN Customer c2
ON c1.FirstName = c2.FirstName and c1.LastName = c2.LastName
AND c1.Uniq_Cust != c2.Uniq_Cust
```